# Task in build.gradle that creates a folder hierarchy

Tags: gradle

I would like to write a Gradle task that automates the creation of a certain folder hierarchy.

I searched extensively the docs, but I cannot seem to find an appropriate way to do that. It puzzles me because it is one of the most simple things in terms of automation.

I tried the following scripts with no luck.

```
task createTree() {
  def d1 = new File(project.buildDir, 'dist/c/')
  d1.mkdir()
}
```

The dumb way also supposing it cannot create a hierarchy at once

```
task createTree() {
  def d1 = new File(project.buildDir, 'dist/')
  d1.mkdir()
  def d2 = new File(project.buildDir, 'dist/c/')
  d2.mkdir()
}
```

Any hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `d1.mkdirs`

[See reference here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

Comment: I was going to say `Isn't what I'm already doing ?`. And then I realized the extra `s`. Oh Java, you never cease to amaze me